# jQuery menu, expand and retract menu on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, toggle

I am working with this example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBCJK/

The problem is that when I have a category expanded, and I click on another one, I want all other expanded categories to retract, leaving only the last one clicked open.
Also if you click a subcategory the menu retracts.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: you should not rely on the height, just add css-classes for the height (answer with javascript-related optimizations are already given by others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset the CSS `max-height: 33px;` rule on all but the last clicked item as follows:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $('.item').not(this).css('max-height', '33px');
    $(this).css('max-height','429px')
});
```

This also ensures the menu doesn't collapse when you click a subcategory, because although you're still enacting a click event on the `.item` div, the max-height won't be removed from the currently 'active' one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works, however it doesn't seem to work in IE 9 and below... or maybe i'm messing something up

Comment: Hi Ivan. I can't test in old browsers right now, but I decided to re-code your example and use a slightly different jQuery method here. [You can find it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzIwy/). It utilises lists, which are generally preferred for menus like this, and the jQuery slideUp() and slideDown() effects to handle the animation, rather than using max-heights and transitions. If it works for you please let me know and I'll edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this toggling would be best handled using a class (for example 'open') to control the styling changes, and show the state.

You can see in [this fiddle](http://codepen.io/mstrutt/pen/hqnwK) my changes, but here is a summary. The new CSS class for the "open" item.

```
#accordion .item.open {
    max-height: 429px;
}
```

and the new click event code:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.open').addBack().toggleClass('open');
});
```

Which selects the item clicked, and all siblings (elements with the same parent) that have a class of 'open' and toggles it (so closes open items and opens closed items).

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can find a better approach by reorganizing your sub items into divs **but** a brute force approach would be to reset the size of your 'item' elements on ANY click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').click(function(){
        $('.item').css('max-height','33px');

        if($(this).css('max-height') == '33px') {
               $(this).css('max-height','429px')
        }
    });
});
```